# Cycle2 Slideshow multiple pager not working

Tags: jquery, slideshow, jquery-cycle2

I am trying to get the pager for Cycle2 to show up in a couple of different locations. I am using the example from the Cycle2 site for multiple pagers. Since no luck in my application I tried stripping everything out and doing in a fiddle. My fiddle gives me the same results as my web application. The pager is tiny and not styled.

I've looked at the source of the Cycle2 example page as well. I can't seem to make the example with no modifications at all work for me like it does on there site. What am I doing wrong.

```
My fiddle which I believe is exact copy of Cycle2 site:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rplace/uLb8u/1/

Cycle2 site showing pager examples...I am interested in multiple pager example (2nd) one down. 
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/pager.php

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "height:40px;" to the .cycle-pager class.

Comment: Adding 40px to the pager class did not work just made the space above and below larger but still tiny dot/bullets versus the larger styled pager.